# Print stored string into xls in a single cell

Tags: perl, xls

I have an array stored with string which I extracted from a text file and wanted to print on xls in a single cell. The below command able to print in the same column but separated row. Finding a way to print in a single cell.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;


my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("result.xls");
my $wrksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("summary");
$wrksheet->write_col(1,0,[@{read_out_your_file_misc("temp_stage.txt")}]);
$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
    
sub read_out_your_file_misc {
    my $content_of_file = [];
    open my $fhh, '<', shift() or die "can't open file:$!";
    while (<$fhh>) {
        chomp;
        #push @{$content_of_file}, $_, $/;
    push @{$content_of_file}, $_;
    }
    return $content_of_file;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result in that cell? you can only write a value, so first you have to build a string representation of the array (i.e. using join)

Comment: oww okay, seldom been here. I have accepted your suggestion to my old question.

Comment: Miguel. Expected to have multiple lines of words or strings in a cell.

Comment: @Blurman I suggest that you go through your other questions and see if you can't accept a lot of the other answers too. It's the polite thing to do when people put time into helping.

Comment: will do. Never knew there is such accept feature here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you supply an array with more than one element in it, more than one row in column `0` (`A`) will be populated by `write_col`. You can `join` the elements in the array to fix that. If this is a pattern that you use frequently, you may even change your `read_out_your_file_misc` function to either return an array *or* a scalar, depending on what you want.

```perl
sub read_out_your_file_misc {
    my $filename = shift or die "ERROR: read_out_your_file_misc needs a filename";
    my $delim = shift || ',';        # make the default delimiter a comma

    open my $fhh, '<', $filename or die "ERROR: $filename: $!";
    my @content_of_file = <$fhh>;    # read the whole file at once
    close $fhh;
    chomp @content_of_file;          # chomp the complete array

    if(wantarray) {    # return an array if that's wanted
        @content_of_file;
    } else {           # else return it as a scalar with $delim between elements
        join($delim, @content_of_file);
    }
}
```

Now depending on the type of the receiving variable, the function behaves differently.

Get the file content as a scalar and populate A2 only:

```perl
my $result = read_out_your_file_misc('temp_stage.txt');
$wrksheet->write_col(1, 0, [$result]);
```

Get the file content as an array and populate from A4 and downwards:

```perl
my @result = read_out_your_file_misc('temp_stage.txt');
$wrksheet->write_col(3, 0, \@result);
```

Comment: This works for printing the file content into one cell. But how could I add a line break between each sentence?

Comment: currently it is printing one long long line

Comment: @Blurman You would replace the default delimiter with `"\n"` which would add a newline between all the lines. I actually made that an option in the answer so you can do: `my $result = read_out_your_file_misc('temp_stage.txt', "\n");` - I commented on the things I did in the code, but if I didn't explain it enough, please ask.

Comment: @Blurman A _sentence_ on the other hand requires a lot more work. Perhaps a _sentence_ regex.

Comment: @Blurman Add a small example file into the question and explain by what rules the different words should go into the different cells and perhaps someone can help. This was my first usage of `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` so I'm sure there are people more qualified out there.

Comment: Hi Ted, sorry for late reply. Yes your suggestion works well. Thank you.